# how to intregrate sabre soap api in android ,Getting All Hotel List and Fight

Tags: java, android, soap, ksoap2, sabredav

I develop Android App using saber dev API but I am not aware properly so please suggest me how to use saber soap API in android.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're developing a (mobile), client, application, you probably should not be trying to directly access Sabre's SOAP API's from that client.

All of Sabre's SOAP API's require an authenticated connection, with many also requiring a session to be instantiated and managed (from a limited pool).

Best practices would be to instantiate your session pool and manage all your SOAP requests from your server, then interact between that server and your Android app in the manner that works best for you.